# Installing Matplotlib via pip on Mac OS X Mavericks failing due to Coacoa error?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pip, osx-mavericks

I've been wrestling with getting the matplotlib library installed for python for a few days now. I've got freetype, XCode, X11, and the bindings sorted out, but now when I try to install matplotlib I get the following error:

```
building 'matplotlib.backends._macosx' extension

gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 
-DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_backends__macosx_ARRAY_API 
-DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include 
-I/usr/X11/include -I/opt/local/include -I. -Iagg24/include 
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 
-c src/_macosx.m 
-o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/_macosx.o

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:161,
     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12,
     from src/_macosx.m:1:
     /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserNotification.h:16:
     error: expected ‘,’ or ‘}’ before ‘__attribute__’
```

This comes along with a number of warnings about deprecated numpy API's, but those seem to be causing no problems. Can anyone tell me what the problem is here?

For the record, I'm using gcc-4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserNotification.h:

```
sudo nano /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUserNotification.h
```

Change line 16 from:

```
NSUserNotificationActivationTypeReplied NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, NA) = 3
```

to:

```
NSUserNotificationActivationTypeReplied /* NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, NA) */ = 3
```

Then retry installing matplotlib:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

That solved it for me!

Source: https://www.mail-archive.com/macosx-port-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg00215.html

Comment: This solved my problem too, where I was trying to build python. What does this header belong to though? What are the chances that it will get upgraded and clobber this manual edit?

Comment: I have hit this error as well, but changing system library headers is an incredibly unwise thing to do - you don't know what other system things depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `which -a gcc-4.2`. If its `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` you aren't using the Xcode supplied gcc. To remedy this, run your build command (or pip, etc) prefixed with `CC=/usr/bin/gcc`. That should fix this error.